# Asynchronously query multiple databases in entity framework 5

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I need to use entity framework to query many databases at once, but I want all the queries to happen at the same time, and for me to be notified when it has all completed.

I have been using the Task Parallel Library and thought may be that can be used to achieve this... by firing off each task in a loop, changing the connection string in each iteration so it would hit a different db.  However, in my experience of task parallel library you only know when each individual task has completed and not a batch.

I am working in an MVC web environment not WPF.

Comment: Can you use VS2012 (i.e. C# 5.0)? Also, you might want to have a look at methods like `Task.WaitAll()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using something like.

```
Task myTask = task.Factory.StartNew( () => {
        some code
} );

Task myTask2 = task.Factory.StartNew( () => {
        some code again
} );
```

then you use the wait method.

```
myTask.Wait();
myTask2.Wait();
```

which will not pass until both tasks are complete.